# WooCommerce condition for is_account_page(), but only the login portion

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I need to test whether the user is on the account page, but only for the login portion as the title states...

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

May be you need to combine `! is_user_logged_in()` with `is_account_page()`, this way:

```
if( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_account_page() ){
    // Test something
}
```

There is also 2 useful hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 'action_woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 10, 0 );
function testing_login_portion(  ) { 
    // Test something 
};
```

Or maybe more useful for you as it targets the my account login form:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start', 'action_woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', 10, 0 );
function testing_login_portion(  ) { 
    // Test something 
};
```