# Customize WooCommerce login form user fields

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, account

I would like to include a placeholder in the woocommerce login form.

Looking at this for a starting point:
[woocommerce add placeholder text to edit account form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49718080/woocommerce-add-placeholder-text-to-edit-account-form):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_form_field_args',      10, 3 );
function custom_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value ) { 
   if ( $args['id'] == 'username' ) {
      $args['placeholder'] = 'My placeholder text';
   }

   return $args;
};
```

Not working as it is. Open to any suggestions.

Comment: I decided to copy the form_login template to my child theme and edit it. But remain interested in the solution to my question.

Answer (score 1):

As the login fields **are hard coded** in `myaccount/form-login.php` template file, **the only way to add placeholder(s)** to those fields, requires [overriding the related template via the active child theme *(or active theme)*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Once you have copied the `myaccount/form-login.php` template file located in WooCommerce plugin under the "templates" folder to *(as explained on the template)*:

```
<?php
/**
 * Login Form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php.
```

Open/Edit `form-login.php` copied file, and add to all desired `<input>` html tags:

```
placeholder="placeholder text"
```

Like for example replacing from line 38 to 45 with the following:

```
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="<?ph esc_html_e("Here type your Username (or email address)"); ?>" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="<?ph esc_html_e(""Here type your password"); ?>" autocomplete="current-password" />
        </p>
```

Then save… You will get something like:

[image]

---

Related threads:

- [WooCommerce condition for is_account_page(), but only the login portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861652/woocommerce-condition-for-is-account-page-but-only-the-login-portion/44889178#44889178)
- [Add a field to Woocommerce registration form and in admin edit user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55947720/add-a-field-to-woocommerce-registration-form-and-in-admin-edit-user/55953515#55953515)
- [Sync additional Billing registration fields with default Wordpress fields in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273947/sync-additional-billing-registration-fields-with-default-wordpress-fields-in-woo/47275358#47275358)

Comment: thanks for your answer. so what is the use of  $fields['account']['account_username']['placeholder']   = __( 'Email*', 'woocommerce' );
    $fields['account']['account_password']['placeholder']   = __( 'Password*', 'woocommerce' );

Comment: another thing: can you edit your answer so the placeholder text is translatable ?

Comment: Done…  The hook `woocommerce_checkout_fields` is for "accoun"t **checkout** fields, when on WooCommerce settings on "account and privacy" section for "Allow customers to create an account during checkout" option is enabled, so in checkout under the billing form, a  checkbox "Create an account?" is displayed (if you are not logged in). Then if you check it, 2 fields are displayed for username and password.

Comment: tu es une machine !

Comment: hahaha ! @loictheaztec tu peux me filer un coup de main sur https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206857/changing-shipping-method-doesnt-update-total-cart-price-in-checkout-page ?

Comment: @Louis Essaye de faire un genre d'exemple reproductible avec du code dans ta question.